# Grouping WHERE conditions with ezSQL v4 PDO

Tags: php, ezsql

How can I group my `WHERE` conditions when using the `selecting` function? I know how to write it in standard SQL, but I can't work this out using ezSQL.

What I'm wanting

```sql
SELECT user_id, user_password, user_password_key
FROM users
WHERE (user_login = $userData OR user_email = $userData) AND user_status=1
```

What I've tried

```
$db->selecting('users', 'user_id, user_password, user_password_key',
               where(eq('user_status', '1', _AND)),
               where(eq('user_login', $userData, _OR ), eq('user_email', $userData )));
```

```
$db->selecting('users', 'user_id, user_password, user_password_key',
               where(eq('user_status', '1')),
               where(eq('user_login', $userData, _OR ), eq('user_email', $userData )));
```

```
$db->selecting('users', 'user_id, user_password, user_password_key',
               $db->where(eq('user_login', $userData, _OR ), eq('user_email', $userData )),
               $db->where('user_status', '1'));
```

```
$db->selecting('users', 'user_id, user_password, user_password_key',
               eq('user_login', $userData, _OR ), eq('user_email', $userData ),
               $db->where('user_status', '1') );
```

It works if I remove the condition for the `user_status`, but when it's in there it just returns `NULL`.

Examples copied from https://github.com/ezSQL/ezSQL#example-for-using-prepare-statements-indirectly-with-above-shortcut-sql-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible with v4 using the following code

```php
$db->selecting(
  'users',
  'user_id, user_password, user_password_key',
  where(
    eq('user_status', '1'),
    grouping(
      eq('user_login', $userData, _OR),
      eq('user_email', $userData)
    )
  )
);
```

More details on the [GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/ezSQL/ezsql/wiki/Shortcut-Methods#grouping)